# Apache POI can not add CustomProperty to Doc

Tags: java, apache-poi, hwpf

I'm trying to add some Custom Properties to an existing document:

```
HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
DocumentSummaryInformation docSumInf = document.getDocumentSummaryInformation();
CustomProperties customProperties = docSumInf.getCustomProperties();

CustomProperty singleProp = null;
//...
singleProp = new CustomProperty();
singleProp.setName(entry.getKey());
singleProp.setType(Variant.VT_LPWSTR);
singleProp.setValue((String) entry.getValue());
//..

customProperties.put(entry.getKey(), singleProp);
docSumInf.setCustomProperties(customProperties);
return document;
```

However, the properties never make it to the file. I tried to

```
document.getDocumentSummaryInformation().getCustomProperties().putAll(customProperties);
```

I also tried

```
document.getDocumentSummaryInformation().getCustomProperties().put(entry.getKey(), singleProp);
System.out.println(document.getDocumentSummaryInformation().getCustomProperties().size() + " Elemente in Map");
```

in a loop. The printed size was allways one.

With the first attemp (docSumInf.setCustomProperties(customProperties);) I printed out customProperties before setting it to docSumInf. There where all new Properties I miss, as soon as I set them to the document summary.

I don't see what I am missing...

Answer (score 1):

```
entry.getKey() = null
```

or `entry.getKey()` has common value for all CustomProperties in the map.

and because of that you have only one element in the map of CustomProperties.

You need to set non null values here

```
singleProp.setName(entry.getKey());
```

> [CustomProperty](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hpsf/CustomProperty.html) class represents custom properties in the document summary information stream. The difference to normal properties is that custom properties have an optional name. If the name is not null it will be maintained in the section's dictionary.

Comment: The entry I use is also from an HashMap: `for(Entry<String, Object> entry : dataMap.entrySet()) { ....}`.  I also tried assigning unique Long values as Keys, that didn't work either. So I am shure the keys are not null..

Comment: make sure in the debugger that entry.getKey() is not null

Comment: I can't debug this code easily because of the enviroment. I printed the value in Log Files, so I confirmed they are not null...

Comment: do you do this `customProperties.put(entry.getKey(), singleProp);` in loop ?

Comment: Yes. To be shure, this is not the mistake, I also added an out-of-the-loop-rubbish property. This is also missing. `singleProp = new CustomProperty();` happens in the loop for every property that does not exist earlier.

Comment: see if you have different entry.getKey() values in every loop cycles